# random loop with conditions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, random, controller, logic

I have a feature called "Browse" that allows users to browse through random profiles.  When a user clicks on "browse" they are immediately taken to a users profile that they are NOT already friends with. What should my controller look like?

Right now I've got:

```
  def browse
    @users = User.all.offset(rand(current_user.matches.count))
    @users.each do |user|
      if !current_user.friends.include?(user)
        @user = user
        return
      end
    end
  end
```

However that doesn't seem to be working. Any advice? I am admittedly bad with blocks, it seems!

Comment: @mu you mean this? User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, login: string, sex: string, birthday: date, zip: string, city: string, state: string, latitude: float, longitude: float, rating_count: integer, score: integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
def browse
   @user = (User.all - current_user.friends).sample
end
```

A better version would be

```
def browse
   @user = User.where('id not in (?)', current_user.friends.map(&:id))
           .offset(rand(current_user.matches.count)).limit(1)
end
```

Also, if you are too concerned about performance, instead of using the offset technique, better use the [randumb](https://github.com/spilliton/randumb) gem to fetch the random record. It uses database specific functions for selecting random records, if available.

Comment: What if there are a million users - `User.all` would load them all into memory.

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra method to your User, something like this:

```
def random_stranger
    self.class.where(%Q{
        id not in (
            select friend_id
            from friends
            where user_id = ?
    }, self.id).
    order('random()').
    limit(1).
    first
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
def browse
    @user = current_user.random_stranger
end
```

If your database doesn't know how to optimize that `not in` then you could replace it with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` combined with `WHERE friend_id is null`.

Comment: great thanks! I'm using postgres, can that handle the 'not in'?

Comment: @weckersham: PostgreSQL should be okay with it, `ORDER BY RANDOM()` can also be problematic but (a) keeping this sort of logic inside the database is your best bet and (b) don't worry too much about it, just keep the logic nicely packed away in one place (i.e. a specific method) so that you can easily fix it up if there is a problem.